# "WORKDIR $DOCKER_MOUNT_DIR cannot normalize nothing" error on multi stage dockerfile build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to incorporate a virtual env in the docker container hence I'm trying to create a Conda environment (line 117-128) with the necessary dependencies needed for my use case which is in the environment.yml file. However, when I try to build the Dockerfile I get the following issue as mentioned in the title.

https://gist.github.com/impaidk/504363033b34406367e774c72544c540

The Dockerfile can be found in the above link.

After adding the lines 117 to 128 I get this problem.
Before adding these lines, I could successfully build the docker file. Can someone please direct me towards what am I wrongly doing here?

```
Removing intermediate container 426298ea76b6
 ---> 68c8b7342cc2
Step 36/54 : RUN echo "conda activate env_vis2mesh" >> ~/.bashrc
 ---> Running in 53949a223622
Removing intermediate container 53949a223622
 ---> 7635492d073b
Step 37/54 : SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
 ---> Running in 992f511d7842
Removing intermediate container 992f511d7842
 ---> aafcba711b55
Step 38/54 : RUN echo '[ ! -z "$TERM" -a -r /etc/motd ] && ( echo "cat <<EOF" ; cat /etc/motd ; echo EOF ) | sh' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
 ---> Running in 0ff2bb34ea36
Removing intermediate container 0ff2bb34ea36
 ---> 643f0f83bbd5
Step 39/54 : COPY motd /etc/
 ---> d10c760f8d25
Step 40/54 : USER $DOCKER_USER
 ---> Running in 9cc835cbdebb
Removing intermediate container 9cc835cbdebb
 ---> 819fae915c5f
Step 41/54 : RUN echo "umask 002" >> $DOCKER_HOME/.bashrc
 ---> Running in 9a24755e10ab
Removing intermediate container 9a24755e10ab
 ---> 5acb97493c3d
Step 42/54 : RUN echo "source $DOCKER_HOME/.version_information.sh" >> $DOCKER_HOME/.bashrc
 ---> Running in affb5a5086b1
Removing intermediate container affb5a5086b1
 ---> 101f71c5c403
Step 43/54 : COPY .version_information.sh $DOCKER_HOME
 ---> bc0bdd3b2437
Step 44/54 : RUN echo "if [[ -f $DOCKER_HOME/.bashrc-appendix ]]; then source $DOCKER_HOME/.bashrc-appendix; fi" >> $DOCKER_HOME/.bashrc
 ---> Running in badd158a5c1f
Removing intermediate container badd158a5c1f
 ---> cd42c89e893c
Step 45/54 : RUN mkdir -p $DOCKER_MOUNT_DIR/src
 ---> Running in 92dceb96a5f8
Removing intermediate container 92dceb96a5f8
 ---> d702d73b89f0
Step 46/54 : RUN mkdir $DOCKER_HOME/.ssh
 ---> Running in 463b4c55314b
Removing intermediate container 463b4c55314b
 ---> 49bc41c8e310
Step 47/54 : ADD templates $DOCKER_HOME/templates
 ---> d62e67ea2fc5
Step 48/54 : RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$DOCKER_HOME/templates/bin' >> $DOCKER_HOME/.bashrc  # using single quotes ensures that $PATH is not replaced here
 ---> Running in aee1b4ca57d9
Removing intermediate container aee1b4ca57d9
 ---> e119faed304a
Step 49/54 : USER root
 ---> Running in acc1ca160be5
Removing intermediate container acc1ca160be5
 ---> 6f3130f1a9a1
Step 50/54 : WORKDIR $DOCKER_MOUNT_DIR
cannot normalize nothing
```

Comment: Environment variables aren't carried over when you go to a new stage in a multi-stage Dockerfile. You need to set them again in the final part of the Dockerfile - or hard-code the working directory.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the information necessary to reproduce the issue _in the question itself_, not behind a link.  Just glancing at the output you've given, I'd note that you can usually safely hard-code details like user names and paths that will be compiled into the image, and that shell dotfiles like `.bashrc`  aren't usually used in Docker at all (`docker run image some-command` will ignore the `.bashrc`).

Answer (score 1):

By design, the environment variables declared in Dockerfile as `ENV` (and also `ARG`) are build-stage specific. And hence, whenever you start a new Docker build-stage (by using the `FROM` parameter), the variables have to be declared once again as per your need.

Just in case you're wondering how the other `ENV` values such as `DOCKER_USER` and `DOCKER_HOME` are (seemingly) working in the newer build stages of your Dockerfile - they're simply being set to null values which won't throw any error during the build (but are surely going to give unpleasant surprises later!!).

Answer (score 1):

What it happens is docker can't find environment variable **$DOCKER_MOUNT_DIR** so you can add a .env file in order to set this env. variable. Then, you must run `docker-compose up` to .env file works.
Also, you can check more information in the [official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) about environment variables.